# Starting a background screen session from ssh.

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, gnu-screen

I would like to shoot a command to server to be run say forever! under "screen session" using ssh.

so I am using something like

```
ssh -t root@server screen -S myinf "python infinit1.py &"
```

where infinit1.py is the script. The problem the "python infinit1.py" doesn't go in a background and neither a screen called "myinf" is created.

I appreciate your hints.

Comment: `nohup` is your friend.  It will keep the command running even after ssh session closes.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great to help me out to integrate screen session as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because screen as invoked by you requires a pty to function. You will need to start screen in detached mode:

```
ssh root@server screen -d -m -S myinf python infinit1.py
```

Comment: it work; may I ask why when I replace "python infinit1.py" with a simple "ls" command it does not work ?

Comment: oh, it does work, but ls will terminate quickly, taking screen with it. You're likely to be too slow to ever see the session :)

Comment: can I specify a pending time or something similar to avoid the quick termination ?! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
 ssh -t root@server "nohup bash -c '( ( /usr/bin/python infinit1.py &> /dev/null ) & )'"
```

this is because the tty that opened need to close and thus cannot keep the command running. to see the output, change /dev/null to an actual file name.

i have not tried to use remote screen so I omitted that. you may be able to get it to work but maybe the syntax is off a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes or the ampersand.  Use the -d -m options to start screen in a detached mode instead.  Take a look at the man page for more infomation.

A working example command line is:

```
ssh $host screen -S myinf -d -m tail -F /var/log/dmesg
```

Comment: sudo for what !? I don't have sudo access !

Comment: It isn't important for the discussion.  I used sudo to read a log file since I don't have infinit1.py on my test host.  The important part is that everything after the options is considered a command line to run inside the screen session.